# Can't run Mongo DB deamon in docker container

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, docker, linux-containers

I'm running docker container in OSX using boot2docker. It is a latest Ubuntu image with mongo installed using official way from package `mongodb-org`.

I can perfectly run `mongod` from command line, but can't run it as a service.

When I'm trying to do `sudo service mongod start` it returns

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mongod start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongod
```

I have tried to do `start mongod` which doesn't have any output. I have tried everything I found in Google, but no luck.

Meanwhile, I have tried to install MySQL using `apt-get` and I can perfectly run it as a service.

Also I have tried to install Mongo from Ubuntu's `mongodb` package which is a older version. Also no problem to run it as a service.

I suspect that there is something wrong with /etc/init.d/mongod script, but don't know exactly what.

Apprieciate any help.

Comment: Are you able to post your Dockerfile?

Comment: You might want to compare with the [docker image I created for MongoDB University's M202 course](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mwmahlberg/m202docker/). In general, it is a bad idea to use services in a Docker container. I have had good results with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org).

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel I'm installing mongo directly within container. Not from the Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm stuck on this same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @emzy, no I didn't figure it out. Just stopped to use Docker because I was just learning how it is working. Don't need it for now.

Answer (score 0):

The init-related commands on the Docker Ubuntu image are dummied out / not working because Upstart (/sbin/init) is not the first process started on the machine.

In general, any service which initializes using Upstart will not run properly in a Docker container unless you start the container with /sbin/init (you probably have to be using the ubuntu-upstart image, and make a bunch of tweaks to it too.)

If you really needed to do it this way, write a traditional init script for mongo and insert it using update-rc.d. Then, starting it with /sbin/service should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the Dockerimage run mongod instead of init/shell/etc?  "One process per container", right?

Use a Dockerfile to create your image, and set the CMD to:
`CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongod.conf"]`